# How does Flixbus get between London and mainland Europe?

Tags: routes, flixbus, english-channel

I've seen many Flixbus routes between London and mainland Europe.

I wonder how Flixbus gets across the English channel; is it using the train or using some ferry?

Comment: I do not know about Flixbus but this Q is about the other routes and non of them seems to have a fixed method: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56539/which-buses-from-london-to-continental-europe-take-the-ferry

Comment: I traveled once from Rotterdam to London and we took the train to cross

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to a [Twitter response](https://twitter.com/flixbus/status/810018680146948096) from 2016, Eurotunnel at least **was** the usual way for FlixBus.

The [review here](https://thehostelgirl.com/europe-by-bus-flixbus-review-london-to-paris-to-rotterdam/) indicates both ferry and Eurotunnel train are possible for FlixBus.

Whether a particular bus takes the ferry or Eurotunnel can be checked (at least sometimes) by looking at the schedule, but the mode of crossing could still change depending on delays etc.

For example, this bus is (supposed to be) taking the tunnel, taking 40 min from Folkestone to Calais

[image]

This bus instead is taking a ferry, taking 1 hour and half to cross from Dover to Calais

[image]

Comment: You can find out about specific services (see my answer)

Answer (score 10):

As of 2020, it varies between services; in order to read about a specific bus, search [here](https://global.flixbus.com/bus/london) (selecting your destination first). Information will appear for both directions.

FOCA and CAFO means the Eurotunnel is used; otherwise the ferry is used.

Answer (score -2):

Flixbus is using Eurotunnel trains to cross. Very quick and efficient and convenient (I wish i could write these about the border passport checkers...)

Comment: Are you sure they only use the Eurotunnel? The answer already here mentions at least one connection which uses a ferry and what I know from other bus companies is that they are fast to change from ferry to tunnel and the other way around, as traffic requires.

Comment: Nope, varies...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).